# Почему AccountManager не дает адрес почтового ящика на Android 6.0.1?

Tags: java, android

Пытаюсь получить адрес почтового ящика вот так:

```
AccountManager manager = (AccountManager) getSystemService(ACCOUNT_SERVICE);
Account[] list = manager.getAccounts();
for(Account account: list){
    if(account.type.equalsIgnoreCase("com.google")){
        etEmail.setText(account.name);
        break;
        }
    }
```

Permission

```
android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"
```

На Андроиде версии 4.4 все нормально, а на 6.0 и выше не определяет. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Начиная, кажется, с 4.4 недостаточно указать нужные пермишены в манифесте. Нужно проверять что ваге приложение их получило и, если не получило, запрашивать. Примерно так

```
public String INTERET = Manifest.permission.INTERNET;
public String READ = Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;
public String WRITE = Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;
public String LOCATION_COARSE = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION;
public String LOCATION_FINE = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
public String PHONE = Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE;

public boolean granted(Activity activity, String... permission) {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    for (String s : permission) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, s) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            list.add(s);
        }
    }
    if (list.isEmpty()) {
        return true;
    }
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, list.toArray(new String[0]), 1);
    return false;
}
```